# Use VBA to filter value equal or greater than TextBox.value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter the Column E to show only results equal or greater than TextBox.Value

So far I have the code to filter if the value is exact match to TextBox.Value, I have tried also something like this : `sh.Range("$E$2:$E$11").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">=A"` but does'n work.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Change()
If Me.TextBox.Value <> "" Then
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet
Dim A As Long

A = Me.TextBox.Value

sh.Range("$E$2:$E$11").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=A
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables don't belong inside quotes. Use the `&` to concatenate:

```vb
Criteria1:=">=" & A
```